# Outlook Calendar 2 week view on Mac

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook, macbook, calendar

So I am using quite a lot of shared calendars with plenty of entries.
Sadly default vertical view is very complicated and I literally can't do required scheduling with that.
In the monthly view, the "list" type view is exactly what I need, but with the monthly view, not all events fit on the screen and there is no way to see them.

On windows, you can simply select 2 weeks on mini-calendar, and that opens 2 weeks in monthly view.
On Mac, I am able to select 2 weeks in the mini calendar, but it still shows a full month.

Is there a way to:
a) Get 2 week view
b) Change view from vertical to horizontal (list)
c) achieve a or b on any other calendar app on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I have done a lot of tests and research on my Outlook for Mac client, but haven't found a way to meet your needs. I'm afraid that you could only use Monthly view or Weekly view at present.

If you really need to implement this function, it is recommended that you could [submit feedback](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-do-i-give-feedback-on-microsoft-office-2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11#platform=macOS) in the Outlook client. I hope Microsoft will pay attention to this problem in the future.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If it is useful, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.